# Correct way to log exceptions using log4j and Solarlint compliant

Tags: java

```
      public static Date convertStringToDate(String cellText) throws 
      ParseException {
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
        try {
          date = dateFormatter.parse(cellText);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
           logger.error("Error in parsing string to date" + e);
        }
        return date;
      }
```

I am using log4j framework to log the exception in my project.I have started using Solarlint to evaluate my static code. But for the logger.error message it says that i need to use Format Specifiers instead of string concatenation. Could some one tell me how to use logger.error("Error in parsing String to Date" + e) in Solarlint compliant fashian.  There are few examples mentioned in other posts but i didn't quite understand that is the reason for me to ask again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your Sonar is crying because you are concatenating `error message` with `Exception e`

```
logger.error("Error in parsing string to date" + e);
```

instead, you can add exception as a parameter to the `logger.error` method. Something like this:

```
logger.error("Error in parsing a string to date: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
```

or

```
logger.error("Error in parsing string to date", e);
```

This will fix the issue of format specifiers instead of string concatenation as well as Sonar issue.